# Using Regex to parse ASCII protocol

Tags: regex, vb.net, parsing, ascii

I'm working on a simple application that interacts with a device via an Telnet session with a ASCII based protocol.

There will be a lot of interaction with the device so i'm looking for a fast way to parse the incoming string. Now the manufacturer was so kind to release there Regex scheme. But since Regex is very new to me i don't understand how to retrieve the value. I know how to match but when i match i want to get the value from it.

Regex scheme

```
NameAndValue := [A-Z_]+:("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|(\\.|[^\s"\\])*)
Value := ("(\\.|[^"\\])*"|(\\.|[^\s"\\])*)
ValueUnquoted := (\\.|[^\s"\\])*
ValueQuoted := "(\\.|[^"\\])*"
CharQuoted := (\\.|[^"\\])
CharUnquoted := (\\.|[^\s"\\])
EscapedChar := \\.
CharCommon := [^\s"\\]
CharEscape := \\
CharQuote := "
CharSpace := \s
```

Example of a response

```
CMD1:"string value" CMD2:1 CMD3:"string value again" <LF> or <CR>+<LF>
```

I've read a lot of documentation and tried lot's of approaches, however someone could point me out in the right direct.

I did however wrote a simple parser that finds the index positions of commands and there values and then uses a substring to retrieve only the value. It works, but i prefer an "nicer" way with the power of Regex.

**--------- EDIT 18-10-2017 ---------**

Request of @VBobCat to provide a more detailed "parsing" requirement.

So let's say i have a object with the properties `Foo` and `Bar` and we have a second object with the properties `cat` and `dog`

Now when i receive the string via telnet i have to parse it to one of those objects. Lucky the string always begins with what it holds. So lets say `x` for object with Foo and Bar and `animal` for object with cat and dog.

Now with the provided Regex i want to parse the values in the string to the properties of the object. Something like:

```
X CMD1_Foo:1 CMD2_Bar:"string value" <LF> or <CR>+<LF>
Object X.Foo = CMD1_Foo.value
Object X.Bar = CMD2_Bar.value
```

OR

```
Animal CMD1_Cat:"Miauw" CMD2_Dog:"woef" <LF> or <CR>+<LF>
Object X.Cat = CMD1_Cat.value
Object X.Dog = CMD2_Dog.value
```

Comment: If you have a parser that works and recognizes the same language, then you probably already have something that's more readable than a bunch of regexes. The list of regexes above seems to be just a description of how to get tokens from the stream, but doesn't actually describe the grammar.

Comment: Thanks, but the current function is al little bit sensitive for specific index position. Also i read everywhere that Regex could be a very fast method to parse strings.

Answer (score 0):

If all your samples are consistent with your example, this could work:

```
Function ParseTelnet(input As String) As DataTable
    Dim retTable As New DataTable
    retTable.Columns.Add("command", GetType(String))
    retTable.Columns.Add("value", GetType(String))
    Dim entries = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(input, "\s+(?=\w+:)")
    Dim pairs = entries.Select(
        Function(entry) If(entry, "").Trim(Chr(9), Chr(10), Chr(13), Chr(32)).Split({":"c}, 2)).Where(
        Function(pair) pair.Count = 2)
    For Each pair In pairs
        If pair(1).StartsWith("""") AndAlso pair(1).EndsWith("""") Then
            retTable.Rows.Add(pair(0), pair(1).Substring(1, pair(1).Length - 2))
        Else
            retTable.Rows.Add(pair(0), pair(1))
        End If
    Next
    Return retTable
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the function. Looks really promising. I did some testing with different Regex functions and your function and logged the speed. For the test it looped 500 times per function. This was the result:

Comment: This was the result: Split Func: 6619,7564 Match Func: 12105,4255 Matches Func: 11945,3395 ParseTelnet Func: 1023,5577 As you can see you're function is very fast. However it does have a flaw, it doesn't removes linefeeds. Als how would you rebuild this code to parse the string to an object. The protocol has different type of command which results in different objects. The first 3 chars in the string defines

Comment: @Gforse, Could you edit you question to post a longer sample, and define exactly how you would like your data to be grouped? That is, do you want each line to be a separate entity?